# Automate Command Prompt using blue prism

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I am try to create a BOT in RPA that will read excel files and then try to execute some standard commands from command prompt using the data in excel files.
I am using Blue Prism for this purpose. While I am able to read excel files and store the data in collection, I am not able to automate command prompt in Blue Prism. I tried to use a code stage in c# to create a cmd process ( code is given below), but it does not recognize the 'Process' class.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new         
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "<command script>";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Any help or guidance in the right direction will be appreciated

Comment: Was able to solve it on my own. It was a dll file issue. It worked once i replaced a dll file.

Answer (score 0):

A more 'Blue Prism-ish' solution would be to launch 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe'' with your needed commandline. But your solution is technically better I believe.

Answer (score 0):

A more 'Blue Prism' solution would be to launch 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe'' with your needed command line. And using navigate-->Send GobalKeys you can complete this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Utility - Environment" BO.

The "Start Process" action is identical to the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Simple question to possibly answer your own question, if you have a series of commands do you think maybe you could store it as batch and program blue prism to create and run this batch every time it runs instead of automating the cmd screen? You could use create file and write the text into a file then run the process to execute the steps then lastly wait till it's finished to check it's output. This way is not best but because it's just sequential cmd statements you can program it to run right more or less and have blueprism be responsible for running and maintaining it

Answer (score 0):

A better solution will be to write the commands you need to execute in a .bat file and call the .bat file as an application using "Utility - Environment" VBO.